# hibernate ORM search an entity using oneToMany List of objects

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql, pojo

I have the following entities.

```
@Entity
public class Blog{
  @Id
  Long id;
  @Column
  String name;
  @Column
  String datePosted;
  @OneToOne(orphanRemoval=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  Metadata metadata;
}

@Entity
public class Metadata{
    @Id
    Long id;
    OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Category> categories;
}

@Entity
public class Category{
    @Id
    Long id;
    @Column
    String name;
    @Column
    Sting type;
}
```

Now I have list of Categories so like this:

```
List<Category> categories;
```

Assume that the above list contains values;
I want to search Blog using **categories**.
Could you help me how to go about that?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, you will firstly need to fix your connections.
To begin with, you will have to add this to the class Blog
(metadata_id should be replaced with the name of the respective database field):

```
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "metadata_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
 Metadata metadata;
```

Also, you will need this statement to the class Metadata:

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "metadata")
 private Blog blog;
```

Now that you have a correct one to one connection between Blog and Metadata (Blog has a foreign key of the Metadata PK), you will have to create a many-to-one and one-to-many connection between the classes: Metadata and Category.

Based on my understanding, one Metadata has a lot of Categories, so you should add this to the class Metadata:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="metadataFK")
 List<Category> categories;
```

Also you will have to add this to the class Category:

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="metadata_id")
 private Metadata metadataFK;
```

After you do all these you should be fine. I am not entirely sure about your question, but I suspect that you will have to use SQL (or HQL) to access Blogs through the Categories.